# SQL Server 2012 Error 26

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012-express

I downloaded SQL Server 2012 Express. Using http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/. I created a local database. Now when I tried to connect to that database using Visual Studio 2010 it throws me error 26

Here is my code:

```
using(SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(localdb)\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;")                          
{
    connectionString.Open(); //error 26
    sql = "insert into Main ([Cable Length1], [Cable Length2]) values(@3',@5')";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connectionString))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3'", 1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5'", 2);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
}
```

Also, I am able to login through SQL Server Management Studio 2012. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Is this a windows app or a web app?  What is the error _message_ you get?

Comment: @Cook - What is the extra 't' for in this line:  `sql = "insert into Main ([Cable Length1], [Cable Length2]) values(@3',@5't)";`?  You have that in your query but not in your:  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5'", 2);`  Remove the 't' and try again.

Comment: Guys this is windows app @Brian: Sorry about 't', but it throws me an error for open itself.

Comment: Also, you can declare your connection string like this (to make it less verbose):  `using(SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;")`.

Comment: @Cook - See my comment above about how you are declaring your `SQL` `connection string`.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("Row inserted !! ");` you're assuming that your code will work successfully ..? wrap that code around a `Try {}catch{}` inside your using never assume.. do proper error trapping / exception handling..

Comment: thanks for the response. I created a local database using SQL server Management Studio. My server name is MyInstance and Database is LocalDBTest but I am still getting error 26 here is my updated code:

Comment: DataTable customerTable = new DataTable("Top5Customers");
                    DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
                    column.ColumnName = "id";
                    customerTable.Columns.Add(column);
                    DataView view = new DataView(customerTable);
                    DataRow row = customerTable.NewRow();
                    row["id"] = 2;
                    customerTable.Rows.Add(row);
                   
                    SqlDataAdapter _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
                    _con.Open();

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all the other problems<sup>1</sup>, you should make up your mind as to whether you're using SQL Server LocalDB or not. I am highly doubtful you've made a private LocalDB instance called `SQLEXPRESS`.

You likely want something along the lines of:

```
new SqlConnection(@"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Trusted_Connection=True;")
```

Or

```
new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=True;")
```

<sup>1</sup> being the following:

- Your `SqlConnection` is called `connectionString`.
- Parameters with quotes in their names.
- Using `master` and then trying to insert into a table called `Main`. System databases are for the system. You are not the system.

I'd expect to see something along the lines of:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=true;")
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Main] ([Cable Length1], [Cable Length2]) VALUES(@3, @5)";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", 1);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", 2);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution: Make sure you are connected to Database and when you launch sql management studio under server name-->select browse for more-->select database engine and then select your local database. You should see the Green Icon and then you do get connected. Thanks for the help guys!